# SOAP Request not returning correct data

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I am trying to consume a Innovata soap web request using the following soap envelope

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:cus="http://CustomDataTimeTableToolKit.com/">
   <soap:Header>
      <cus:WSAuthenticate>
         <cus:CustomerRefCode>XYZ</cus:CustomerRefCode>
         <cus:Password>XXXXXXXX</cus:Password>
         <cus:WebServicesRefCode>xxx</cus:WebServicesRefCode>
      </cus:WSAuthenticate>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <cus:GetSchedules>
         <cus:_sSchedulesSearchXML>&lt;GetSchedules_Input customerCode="XXX" productCode="external" dptCode="EDI" dptCodeType="STA" arvCode="LHR" arvCodeType="STA" flightDaysRange="3" MM="10" DD="11" YYYY="2012" searchType="B" cnxType="B" IncludeSummary="false" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="GetSchedules_Input.xsd"/&gt;</cus:_sSchedulesSearchXML>
      </cus:GetSchedules>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I wrote the following PHP Code which seems to work but not return the correct data!

```
<?php


    $customerCode = 'XXX';
    $password = 'XXXX';

    $dptCode = 'EDI';
    $dptCodeType='STA';
    $arvCode='LHR'; 
    $arvCodeType='STA';


    $client = new SoapClient('http://ctk.innovataw3svc.com/ctk.asmx?WSDL', array('trace'=>1));
    $client->__setSoapHeaders(array(
        new SoapHeader('http://CustomDataTimeTableToolKit.com/', 
            'WSAuthenticate', 
            array(
                'CustomerRefCode' => $customerCode,
                'Password' => $password,
                'WebServicesRefCode' => 'TKC'
            )
        )
    ));
    $date = new DateTime();
    $in = new stdClass();
    $in->_sSchedulesSearchXML = sprintf(
        '<GetSchedules_Input customerCode="%s" productCode="external" dptCode="%s" dptCodeType="%s" arvCode="%s" arvCodeType="%s" flightDaysRange="3" MM="%s" DD="%s" YYYY="%s" searchType="B" cnxType="B" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="GetSchedules_Input.xsd" />',
        $customerCode, 
        $dptCode, 
        $dptCodeType, 
        $arvCode, 
        $arvCodeType, 
        $date->format('m'), 
        $date->format('d'),
        $date->format('Y')
    );


    try{
        $result = $client->GetSchedules($in);
        print_r($result);
    }
    catch(SoapFault $e){
        echo "Soap Fault: ".$e->getMessage();
    }
```

The output is the following:

```
stdClass Object ( [GetSchedulesResult] => S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S 319 0 S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S 319 0 S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S 319 0 M M M M M S S S S S S S S S S S S 319 0 S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S 319 0 M M M M M S S S S S S S S S S S S 319 0 M M M M M S S S S S S S S S S S S 319 0 M M M M M S S S S S S S S S S S S 319 0 S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S 319 0 S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S 319 0 S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S 320 0 S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S 319 0 M M M M M M M M M M M M M M M M M ER4 0 S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S 319 0 S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S 319 0 S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S 319 0 S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S 319 0 M M M M M S S S S S S S S S S S S 319 0 M M M M M S S S S S S S S S S S S 319 0 M M M M M M M M M M M M M M M M M ER4 0 M M M M M S S S S S S S S S S S S 319 0 S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S 319 0 M M M M M S S S S S S S S S S S S 319 0 M M M M M M M M M M M M M M M M M ER4 0 M M M M M S S S S S S S S S S S S 319 0 )
```

I really don't see where the problem is, any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Problem is: I cannot see where the problem is either. You do a soap request and get a result - works for me to this point. What were you expecting instead?

Comment: Have you tried to echo the SOAP data?  I'd try looking at the `$client->__getLastResponses()`, as well as `$client->__getLastRequest()`;

Comment: The expected output is (pasted on pastebin) http://pastebin.com/p7amXHQc

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So, looks like you were outputting your debug to a web page, and the XML was getting stripped while the browser tried to render the page.  The output you were seeing was the meal codes, stops, etc.

In other words, you were always getting the response you expected.

If that's the case, don't use the `__getLastResponse()`, but just handle the $result as an object, and parse it as needed.

Comment: You happen to output your debug result into an HTML page - this hides every XML tags that you were expecting, but they are there! Always add a call to `htmlspecialchars()` in this case.